# javascript, prevent clicking the element below the element clicked on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a website that have a expandable side navigation bar. When the user extends the sidebar on mobile is extend the width of the page. Therefore this side bar has a close button in the top right corner.

However on the top nav bar, the logout button is in the top right corner. So if the user has a slightly long touch to close the sidebar on mobile, it is triggering the logout button underneath it as well.

**top bar:**

[image: ![enter image description here]

**extended side bar:**

[image]

**javascript:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('click touchstart','.menu-toggle',function(){
    $('.main-menu').toggleClass('toggled')
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable the logout button temporarily for short time once the user clicks close button.

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('click touchstart','.menu-toggle',function(event){

    //Instead of disabling by css, you could also use jquery method .prop('disabled',true)

    $('#logout-btn').css({
    "pointer-events": "none",
    "touch-action":"none"
   })
    $('.main-menu').toggleClass('toggled')
    event.stopPropagation();
    
    //I used delay, you could use setTimeout also.
    $('#logout-btn').delay(200).queue(function (next) { 
        $(this).css({
          "pointer-events": "auto",
          "touch-action":"auto"
        })
        next(); 
   });
  });
});
```

Comment: This throws `Unexpected token ';'` for `"pointer-events": "none";`

Comment: By mistake, should be comma. I Edited it